# why is my laptop-mode configuration being ignored?

Tags: cpu, laptop, laptop-mode

I am running Debian GNU/Linux Jessie (testing) on my laptop. I enabled the systemd laptop-mode service:

```
$ sudo laptop_mode
Laptop mode 
enabled, active [unchanged]
```

and in my `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/cpufreq.conf` I have (trimmed everything else, using defaults)

```
CONTROL_CPU_FREQUENCY=1
BATT_CPU_GOVERNOR=powersave
LM_AC_CPU_GOVERNOR=powersave
NOLM_AC_CPU_GOVERNOR=performance
```

which are modes supported by all my CPUs:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
performance powersave
```

However, if I reboot with AC (or plug in the mains) and look in

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor 
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
```

all the CPUs are using powersave.

So why is my config being ignored? How can I fix this?

Relevant info:

- I do not have `pm-utils` or `acpid` installed (because they are known to conflict with `systemd` and `laptop-mode` in various ways)
- this was on a fresh install and there are no legacy CPU config options left over in any other laptop-mode config file.

Answer (score 4):

AHA! It turns out that my CPUs support [`pstate`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt) and this seems to show up as `powersave` mode but in actual fact it is a custom governor.

With this, it means that laptop-mode ignores all the `cpufreq` settings and instead looks in `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/intel_pstate.conf`. In here, custom scaling rules can be applied (and I confirm that they are picked up!)

Indeed, there are a few other Intel specific modules here and I'm off to read about them all.